# NetBeans giving error saying a project was deleted when it was never opened

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I've just cloned a project from a GitHub repository and proceeded to attempt to open the project in NetBeans, using the "Import Project from existing sources" option, but I was stopped by an error telling me that a project was already managing that folder.

[the error can be seen here http://puu.sh/2v8ED](http://puu.sh/2v8ED)

```
Project folder is managed by a project Craftys.
Instead of creating a new project just open it. If by a chance you just deleted the project Craftys than restart the IDE to reuse the folder.
```

I do not have a project named `Craftys` in my project list, nor have I ever.

This project uses Maven, and the word "Craftys" as opposed to `Craftys2` (the name of the folder) seems to come from the pom.xml.

When I remove the pom.xml from the base directory, the project opens, but then I cannot create a pom.xml, so all the dependencies' usages give errors.

So, my question is, **How would I import this existing project while still allowing it to use maven?** I've searched around and have not found any others with this same issue, and I'm confused on what I should do.

[Here's a link to a similar project that I've been having the same issue with.](https://github.com/prism/Prism)

Comment: Forget about "Import Project from Existing Sources". These are Netbeans (enabled) projects already, just open them as the error message explicitly stated to do (File->Open, then browse to the project location).

Comment: @Perception Oh, thanks so much! I guess I read the message wrong, I was thinking it meant to literally open the project, as in, it already exists and you can open it in the sidebar. This worked, you should make it an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about "Import Project from Existing Sources". These are Netbeans (enabled) projects already, just open them as the error message explicitly stated to do (File->Open, then browse to the project location).

[image: Netbeans - Open Dialog]

Comment: yes, just open the Maven project, don't generate the ant script for it.